# Html2Canvas not working on Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, html2canvas

I have the following code, it works fine on Firefox but the image is not being rendered on Chrome for some reason, any ideas?

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Test Html2Canvas</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.6.3.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="html2canvas.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.plugin.html2canvas.js"></script> 
</head>
<body>
testing
<img src="someImage.jpg"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {
    html2canvas( [ document.body ], {
        onrendered: function( canvas ) {
              document.body.appendChild( canvas );
            }
    });
};
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

The image may not have loaded before the `html2canvas` attempts to draw it. Attempting to draw an image that hasn't loaded silently does nothing, so you get nothing.

Try wrapping your `html2canvas` call in a `window.onload` handler. NOT jQuery's `ready` because you NEED the code to run ONLY when all images etc. have fully loaded.

Comment: Good thinking, but it still doesn't work, I'm seeing this error on Chrome's console: "Unable to get image data from canvas because the canvas has been tainted by cross-origin data."

Comment: Ah. That would mean you redacted your code. The image MUST come from the same origin (host, port, scheme) otherwise it "taints" the canvas.

Answer (score 1):

It will not work if you run this html file without any web server . If you are playing around on your PC then install XAMPP or any other web server (Easiest option http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html) and put the image ,JavaScript and HTML code in C:\xampp\htdocs (if C dirive is your installation drive) and run using the server. 
I have tested it in Chrome and its working.

Comment: Why on earth wouldn't it work locally ?It's just a html file, there's no need of a webserver.

Comment: @Vicky no need to web server bro, all codes run in frontend and of course processing with your browser,html2canvas is a javascript library not like phantomjs which need a web server to run